# Irreducibility of polynomials in two variables

Tags: polynomials

Mathematica tests polynomials in several variables for irreduciblity. How can I find out what sufficient conditions for irreducibilty it uses?

Comment: About `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` ? `Factor`?

Comment: One such is absolute irreducibility: whether the Newton polygon is indecomposable. A factorization will be tried when this first test is inconclusive.